# Remove list entries that match any entry in another list

Tags: python

I have a list of curse words I want to match against other list to remove matches.  I normally use list.remove('entry') on an individual basis, but looping through a list of entries against another list - then removing them has me stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're writing a profanity filter? Good luck with the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)!

Comment: Does order matter? (if yes, take the filter, if no, take sets)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> words = ['there', 'was', 'a', 'ffff', 'time', 'ssss']
>>> curses = set(['ffff', 'ssss'])
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in curses, words)
['there', 'was', 'a', 'time']
>>>
```

It could also be done with list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in words if x not in curses]
```

Comment: Making `curses` a list is a bad idea - `in` is O(1) for a set, O(n) for a list.

Answer (score 4):

Use sets.

```
a=set(["cat","dog","budgie"])
b=set(["horse","budgie","donkey"])
a-b
->set(['dog', 'cat'])
```

Comment: What if I already have the lists define?  Could I do:

a = ['bad_word1', 'bad_word2' ]
b = ['a', 'b', 'bad_word1' ]

set1 = set(a)
set2 = set(b)

set1 - set2

a = set1
b = set2

Comment: notice that sets could mess the order of the words and also would remove duplicate words from your list. Also it should be faster I guess.